# Example for an algorithm with greater than n splits

Tags: time-complexity, master-theorem

I was doing the derivation for masters theorem using the tree method and I noticed something.

So we have:

$T(n)=a*T(n/b) + n^c$

From this: we notice, the last level of the tree will have      $a^(log_b_n)$  splits, which equals $n^(log_b_a)$

Now, if $a=b$, I get n splits in the last level, which is I've seen used in quick sort and merge sort, and if a

Is there a practical example for greater than n splits? 
Where we actually repeat operations for elements?

*Also, math overflow formatting doesn't seem to work. Would appreciate if anyone helps.

Answer (score 1):

The classical [matrix multiplication by divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm#Divide_and_conquer_algorithm) would be such an example. The recurrence relation is: T(n)=8T(n/2)+ Theta(n^2). Another would be [Straussen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm#Asymptotic_complexity).

Math notation is (sadly) limited to only a few stackexchange sites.

Comment: But for any such case, we would store answers and never recalculate, right?

Comment: It is not a recalculation as you may think of it. Look at the matrix multiplication. At each level of the recursion you go from n to n/2, so you half the problem size. At the same time the effort to compute that level is 8. You may think about it like this: To solve a problem you may divide it into two smaller problems but you may need a little bit more information that half to solve half of the problem.